# Does the classloader load a class file if the corresponding class is never used?

Tags: java, classloader

To make my question more clear, consider following use-case:

Suppose there is a package that permits a set of operations on a given platform, for example a class to edit the registry on Windows.
This package does not exist on other platforms, as there is no equivalent operation on other operating system.

For the sake of simplicity, consider

windows/Registry.java

```
package windows;

public class Registry {

  static Registry instance = null;
  static{
    System.out.println("print from static block");
  }

  private Registry() {
    System.out.println("Registry instance created!");
  }

  public static synchronized Registry getInstance() {
    if (null == instance) {
      instance = new Registry();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo called.");
  }
}
```

and the class where I am going to conditionally use the registry: main/Main.java

```
package main;

import windows.Registry;

public class Main {

  public static void test1(boolean onWindows) {
    if (onWindows) {
      Registry instance = Registry.getInstance();
      System.out.println("We are on Windows: ");
      instance.foo();
    } else {
      System.out.println("We are somewhere else!");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Entered main");
    boolean onWindows = args.length > 0 ? Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]) : false;
    test1(onWindows);
  }
}
```

The question is, if no function or class is explicitly executed in `Main.class`, is it guaranteed that no code from `Registry.class` is executed?

I was able to test this example on multiple Desktop Platforms and with different java versions, but I would like to know if this behavior is documented and one can rely on it, if it thus the expected behavior also on other platforms, like android or embedded version of the JRE.

In case there is no such guarantee, as a (maybe custom) classloader might decide to load all `.class` files in the classpath, can I assume that the code will work without a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` if `onWindows` is false and I remove `Registry.class` from the classpath?

The behavior I've observed so far is

```
rm -rf bld; mkdir bld && javac -d bld src/windows/Registry.java src/main/Main.java && java -classpath bld main.Main true
Entered main
print from static block
Registry instance created!
We are on Windows: 
foo called.

rm -rf bld; mkdir bld && javac -d bld src/windows/Registry.java src/main/Main.java && java -classpath bld main.Main false
Entered main
We are somewhere else!


rm -rf bld; mkdir bld && javac -d bld src/windows/Registry.java src/main/Main.java && rm -r bld/windows && java -classpath bld main.Main false
Entered main
We are somewhere else!

rm -rf bld; mkdir bld && javac -d bld src/windows/Registry.java src/main/Main.java && rm -r bld/windows && java -classpath bld main.Main true
Entered main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: windows/Registry
        at main.Main.test1(Main.java:9)
        at main.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: windows.Registry
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 2 more
```

Are those behavior (lazy classloader and removing `Registry.class`) defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The question is, if no function or class is explicitly executed in `Main.class`, is it guaranteed that no code from `Registry.class` is executed?

That doesn't touch directly on class *loading*, but rather on class *initialization*, which is the first point at which any code from the class in question gets executed.  Specifically, static initialization blocks and the initializers of static members are executed during this stage.  The class in question must already have been loaded and verified at this point, but it might have been loaded an arbitrary amount of time earlier.

Per [JLS 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1),

> A class or interface T will be initialized immediately before the
> first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A `static` method declared by T is invoked.
> - A `static` field declared by T is assigned.
> - A `static` field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable

Thus, if you never instantiate the class or access access any of its static methods or fields (except to read a static field that is a "constant variable") then no code from the class will ever be executed.

But that a class does not get initialized does not mean that no attempt will be made to *load* it.  The JLS does not forbid implementations from loading classes prospectively.  In fact, [JLS 12.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2.1) specifically says:

> a class loader may cache binary representations of classes and interfaces, **prefetch them based on expected usage**, or **load a group of related classes together**.

Thus, no, it is not safe to rely on the application represented by your class `main.Main` to run without a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` or other loading error when class `windows.Registry` cannot be loaded, regardless of whether it can be expected actually to be used.  However, you *can*, under the right circumstances, rely on that class not being initialized, and therefore no code from it being executed.

Comment: Thank for the reply with official references, I'll dig through them.

Why would a non appositely created class-loader try to load `Registry` if there is no file with such name, and no instance is created? Through reflection it would be possible to detect member variables, but not locals

JLS 12.2.1 also states: "It is the responsibility of a class loader, however, to reflect loading errors only at points in the program where they could have arisen without prefetching or group loading"

Does that mean that in case of error, it would be suppressed until `Registry.class` is actually needed?

Comment: @fekir, a ClassLoader might attempt to load `windows.Registry` when it links `main.Main`, because it sees (very clearly at that point) that the latter references the former.  This could be considered either as "prefetching based on expected usage" or as a variety of group loading.

Comment: I see, and what about my last comment ("t is the responsibility of a class loader, however, to reflect loading errors only at points in the program where they could have arisen without prefetching or group loading")?

It seems that it makes it non-compliant to throw `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` if `Registry` is never used.
Ie `NoClassDefFoundError` should not be thrown when the `.class` file is not found, but when it's usage is required (and not found).

Comment: @fekir, The details of linking classes (`main.Main` in this case) are described in [section 5.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4) of the Java VM specification.  They are somewhat flexible, and they explicitly permit a JVM to resolve symbolic references appearing in a class eagerly, at the time the class is linked.  In your case, that would have the result of attempting to load `windows.Registry` as part of linking `main.Main`, which must precede executing any code the latter class. [...]

Comment: [...] Although I said that loading `windows.Registry` at that time could be considered prefetching or group loading, that remark was in fact a *non sequitur*.  It is not necessary to rely on prefetching or group loading to justify the JVM attempting to load `windows.Registry` as a result of linking `main.Main`, and therefore the VM is not precluded from failing with an error at that point if it cannot, in fact, load `windows.Registry`.

Comment: Also [section 5.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4) states that "[...] any error detected during resolution must be thrown at a point in the program that [...] uses a symbolic reference to the class or interface."

Thus it seems to me that I should get a `NoClassDefFoundError`, only when `Registry.getInstance();` is executed.

(in the meantime still accepting your answer, as it provided all necessary informtions)